# How do I test Game Center and In-App Purchases with Test-Flight (iOS)

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, game-center, testflight

I have exported my app from Construct 2 and have tested its playable features with success using Test-Flight with a first build from iTunes Connect. However, I still need to test the in-app purchases and Game Center, and I am struggling to do so. I have looked at testflight and sandbox mode - but everything is so darn confusing! I believe I have set it up correctly but I would be happy to answer any queries still!
Help is very much appreciated!